# Can i replace the Route between 2 destinations in Mapkit using MKOverlayRenderer to show a custom Route which show the distance like below Picture?

Tags: ios, swift, routes, mapkit, mapkitannotation

[image]

I want to replace the default route between 2 destinations with a custom one?
All i found was to replace the route by setting a custom MKOverlayRenderer ex: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/draw-route-mapkit-tutorial
which explain how to replace the route color and width but i couldn't find anything to help me to make custom route like the provided image.

Comment: Starting point: https://github.com/ivan114/IVBezierPathRenderer

Comment: Thank you i will try to find a solution to draw the above result in the BezierPath.